Google Doc triggered date update
I have a google doc in which I would like to create a triggered auto date update. For example, each Friday at 5 PM a date that is part of the header should change to the following Monday (using date arithmetic) . How do I do this?
I understand how to do a timed trigger.  I also know to bring up APP Script in the Google Doc.  I'm struggling with getting the code (which I think should not be difficult - just a calculated date in the header text.  Help very appreciated.)  Peter

I see that you are a fairly new user here at StackOverflow. Please do read how to ask first before asking another question as your post might be closed if it doesn't meet the criteria of it being a good question. Enjoy your stay at StackOverflow.

Broad Steps

Create a new Apps Script project. It can be a bound or standalone project.
Write a JavaScript function. Use either Documents Service or the Advanced Documents Service to update the Google document.
Create a Google Apps Script time-driven trigger either using code or manually.

References

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Running a trigger at a specific date and time
In Google Apps Script, you might use an installable time-driven trigger. For the case mentioned, Friday at 5pm, set the time-driven trigger type to Week Timer, select the day of the week as Every Friday and set the time of day as 5pm to 6 pm. Just so you know, time-driven triggers can not be set to run at a specific time, but you might take a few measures to get something done at a specific time.
Using date arithmetic
There are many ways to do date arithmetic in JavaScript. It's worth noting that newbies might need help to get this to work.
Besides date arithmetic, getting a string representation of date might also take a lot of work to catch. Depending on your locale, you may find helpful methods like Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString and Intl.DateTimeFormta methods among other JavaScript methods. It's worth noting that Google Apps Script has some stuff that might help, like the Utilities.formatDate and Utilities.formatString.
